# How to skip column when reading CSV file?

Tags: r, csv

In accordance with the documentation of `read.csv`, `colClasses` argument:

> Possible values are ..., "NULL" (when the column is skipped), ...

But looks like it doesn't work when `col.names` is used:

```
columnHeaders <- c("column1", "column2", "column_to_skip")
columnClasses <- c("factor", "factor", NULL)
data <- read.csv(fileCSV, header = FALSE, sep = ",", col.names = columnHeaders, colClasses = columnClasses)
```

In result `data` contains 3 columns, including `column_to_skip`. What is the proper way to read csv without this last column?

Comment: After you do this, check out how much easier it is with `data.table::fread()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `"NULL"` instead of `NULL`:

```
csv <- "1,2,3
4,5,6"
read.csv(text = csv, header = FALSE, colClasses = c("integer", "integer", "NULL"))
#   V1 V2
# 1  1  2
# 2  4  5
```